# Global variables in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, global-variables

I have a problem where i'm initialising a variable on the scope in a controller. Then it gets changed in another controller when a user logs in. This variable is used to control things such as the navigation bar and restricts access to parts of the site depending on the type of user, so its important that it holds its value. The problem with it is that the controller that initialises it, gets called again by angular some how and then resets the variable back to its initial value.

I assume this is not the correct way of declaring and initialising global variables, well its not really global, so my question is what is the correct way and is there any good examples around that work with the current version of angular?

Comment: Since this is #1 google result: 

You can now use app.constant() and app.value() to create app-wide constants and variables. More here: http://bit.ly/1P51PED

Answer (score 500, accepted):

You've got basically 2 options for "global" variables:

- use a `$rootScope` http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope
- use a service http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

`$rootScope` is a parent of all scopes so values exposed there will be visible in all templates and controllers. Using the `$rootScope` is very easy as you can simply inject it into any controller and change values in this scope. It might be convenient but has all the [problems of global variables](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Services are singletons that you can inject to any controller and expose their values in a controller's scope. Services, being singletons are still 'global' but you've got far better control over where those are used and exposed.

Using services is a bit more complex, but not that much, here is an example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('UserService', function() {
  return {
      name : 'anonymous'
  };
});
```

and then in a controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, UserService) {
    $scope.name = UserService.name;
}
```

Here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/BRWPM/2/

Comment: From the [Angular FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):  Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.

Comment: I'm using the [Express + Angular seed by Btford](https://github.com/btford/angular-express-seed). If I set a variable on the $rootScope in Controller1 say and move to another url (powered by Controller2 say) I can access this variable. However if I refresh the page on Controller2 then the variable is no longer accessible on $rootScope. If I am saving user data on sign in how can I ensure this data is accessible elsewhere even on page refresh?

Comment: I've added a more complete version of the original [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LZszu/)

Comment: Does anyone have examples of using rootScope in this case?

Comment: I prefer to have a MainCtrl that encompasses my entire app.  I keep any global values on that level. ``$scope.main.user = { name: "anonymous" }`` and then all my child ctrl's have access to the $scope.main object.

Comment: @JakobStoeck I have been waffling on whether or not to use a service for environmental values. Ended up using $provider.config() on my app module.

Comment: interestingly the angular seed DOES use a service only for a value. and my question is, isn't it better to use a service as this can be tested but anything to rootScope nor in config can not be easily tested. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JakobStoeck Combine this with this answer and you're left with putting the data on the rootScope. I don't think that's right either. What's the angular way of storing and returning globally used bits of data?

Comment: @JakobStoeck So why there is a `value` recipe?! Actually its only purpose in life is store and return a value!

Comment: Then what's the alternative @JakobStoeck? sessionStorage?

Comment: I'm curious what the disadvantages are of a service that is specifically for storing values. Isolated, only injected where you need it, and easily testable. What is the downside?

Comment: does using service as global variables persist between page refreshes ?
It works fine and the value is persisted between views till I refresh... and it became blank ?! am I doing it wrongly ?!

Comment: @artmees You can store your variables into cookies then restore them on refresh (during app loading)

Comment: oh god, why everybody is afraid of reaal global variables, if you know what your app will consist of, just make a real global js variable instead overcomplicating stuff

Comment: I updated the fiddle, as references passed by property will not be bind to properties of type of e.g. boolean. http://jsfiddle.net/BRWPM/1456/

Comment: If I create the service as mentioned above, how can i update its variable values? let's say name must be updated from controller.

Comment: In 2016 I can't find in FAQ any mention about constants.

Comment: @ksa_coder, I know it's late but for future readers: if you inject `SomeService` into `SomeController` (`self`) and wanted to set the `name` variable from there you'd do: `SomeService.name = self.name;`. Know that the service is a singleton and therefore its `name` variable could be changed from any component which has it injected.

Comment: I think if we have multiple controllers, say a lot. And we need some "global variables" available for all controllers, let's say the userId. Then By using Services will required a lot of service injections into controllers. In this scenario I'll prefer to use $rootScope but what is the best practice?

Answer (score 100):

If you just want to store a value, according to the [Angular documentation on Providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), you should use the Value recipe:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.value('clientId', 'a12345654321x');
```

Then use it in a controller like this:

```
myApp.controller('DemoController', ['clientId', function DemoController(clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}]);
```

The same thing can be achieved using a Provider, Factory, or Service since they are "just syntactic sugar on top of a provider recipe" but using Value will achieve what you want with minimal syntax.

The other option is to use `$rootScope`, but it's not really an option because you shouldn't use it for the same reasons you shouldn't use global variables in other languages. It's [advised](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) to be used sparingly.

Since all scopes inherit from `$rootScope`, if you have a variable `$rootScope.data` and someone forgets that `data` is already defined and creates `$scope.data` in a local scope you will run into problems.

---

If you want to modify this value and have it persist across all your controllers, use an object and modify the properties keeping in mind Javascript is pass by ["copy of a reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/1157020):

```
myApp.value('clientId', { value: 'a12345654321x' });
myApp.controller('DemoController', ['clientId', function DemoController(clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.change = function(value) {
        clientId.value = 'something else';
    }
}];
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/x8qrh/1/)

Comment: When I changed the value on one view, the new value is not persistent. How come? Can you please update your answer and let us see how your `clientId` can be updated?

Comment: @DeanOr Is it possible to preserve the updated value between refreshes of the page?  The value gets reinitialised if I refresh the page.

Comment: You'll have to use something else for that like a cookie, local storage, or database.

Comment: I really like this one the best. I can now modify by build process for dev, stage, and prod

Comment: There is a simple article explaining the use of constants and values similar to Global variables: https://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/

Comment: "The other option is to use $rootScope, but it's not really an option because you shouldn't use it for the same reasons you shouldn't use global variables in other languages. It's advised to be used sparingly."

Sparingly doesn't mean never. If you have a real and proper use for a global variable you SHOULD do it. That's the whole point of global variables, that's why they exist.

Answer (score 37):

Example of AngularJS "global variables" using `$rootScope`:

Controller 1 sets the global variable:

```
function MyCtrl1($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.name = 'anonymous'; 
}
```

Controller 2 reads the global variable:

```
function MyCtrl2($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.name2 = $rootScope.name; 
}
```

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/natefriedman/3XT3F/1/

Comment: This does not work in views of isolated scope directives. See http://jsfiddle.net/3XT3F/7/. But you can use $root to work around it. See http://jsfiddle.net/3XT3F/10/. Thanks to [@natefaubion](https://github.com/natefaubion) for [pointing it out](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4068#issuecomment-24815901)

Comment: on refresh, $rootScope value would be empty.

Comment: hardcoding the $rootScope.name equals some value..actually we need to read it and set it there.

Answer (score 25):

In the interest of adding another idea to the wiki pool, but what about AngularJS' [`value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#value) and [`constant`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant) modules? I'm only just starting to use them myself, but it sounds to me like these are probably the best options here.

Note: as of the time of writing, Angular 1.3.7 is the latest stable, I believe these were added in 1.2.0, haven't confirmed this with the changelog though.

Depending on how many you need to define, you might want to create a separate file for them. But I generally define these just before my app's `.config()` block for easy access. Because these are still effectively modules, you'll need to rely on dependency injection to use them, but they are considered "global" to your app module.

For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .value('debug', true)
  .constant('ENVIRONMENT', 'development')
  .config({...})
```

Then inside any controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function(debug, ENVIRONMENT), {
    // here you can access `debug` and `ENVIRONMENT` as straight variables
  })
```

From the initial question is actually sounds like static properties are required here anyway, either as mutable (value) or final (constant). It's more my personal opinion than anything else, but I find placing runtime configuration items on the `$rootScope` gets too messy, too quickly.

Comment: I find the value module very useful and concise. especially when you bind it to a $scope variable within a controller, so that changes within that controller's logic or view are bound to the global variable/value/service

Answer (score 22):

```
// app.js or break it up into seperate files
// whatever structure is your flavor    
angular.module('myApp', [])    

.constant('CONFIG', {
    'APP_NAME' : 'My Awesome App',
    'APP_VERSION' : '0.0.0',
    'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID' : '',
    'BASE_URL' : '',
    'SYSTEM_LANGUAGE' : ''
})

.controller('GlobalVarController', ['$scope', 'CONFIG', function($scope, CONFIG) {

    // If you wish to show the CONFIG vars in the console:
    console.log(CONFIG);

    // And your CONFIG vars in .constant will be passed to the HTML doc with this:
    $scope.config = CONFIG;
}]);
```

In your HTML:

```
<span ng-controller="GlobalVarController">{{config.APP_NAME}} | v{{config.APP_VERSION}}</span>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
localStorage.username = 'blah'
```

If you're guaranteed to be on a modern browser.  Though know your values will all be turned into strings.

Also has the handy benefit of being cached between reloads.

Comment: Heh, I'm going to store all variables via localStorage. We will even have some sort of persistency then! Also,  to get around the string limitation, let's store the .toString() of a function then eval it when needed!

Comment: like already mentioned by @Shaz, this has the problem of persistency

Answer (score 7):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but when Angular 2.0 is released I do not believe`$rootScope` will be around. My conjecture is based on the fact that `$scope` is being removed as well. Obviously controllers, will still exist, just not in the `ng-controller` fashion.Think of injecting controllers into directives instead. As the release comes imminent, it will be best to use services as global variables if you want an easier time to switch from verison 1.X to 2.0.

Comment: I agree, putting data directly onto $rootScope is against Angular's whole purpose. Take a bit of time and organize your code properly and it will help you, not only in the AngularJS 2.x upgrade, but generally throughout your app's development as it grows more complex.

Comment: If $rootScope is removed, just write a new service that's called "$rootScope" :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the environment variable `$window` so that a global variable declare outside a controller can be checked inside a `$watch`

```
var initWatch = function($scope,$window){
    $scope.$watch(function(scope) { return $window.globalVar },
        function(newValue) {
            $scope.updateDisplayedVar(newValue);
    });
}
```

Becareful, the digest cycle is longer with these global values, so it is not always real-timed updated. I need to investigate on that digest time with this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I just found another method by mistake :

What I did was to declare a `var db = null` above app declaration and then modified it in the `app.js` then when I accessed it in the `controller.js`
I was able to access it without any problem.There might be some issues with this method which I'm not aware of but It's a good solution I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will not force to inject `$rootScope` in controller.

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.Currency = 'USD';
});
```

You can only use it in run block because config block will not provide you to use service of $rootScope.

Answer (score -1):

It's actually pretty easy. (If you're using Angular 2+ anyway.)

Simply add

```
declare var myGlobalVarName;
```

Somewhere in the top of your component file (such as after the "import" statements), and you'll be able to access "myGlobalVarName" anywhere inside your component.

Answer (score -2):

You can also do something like this ..

```
function MyCtrl1($scope) {
    $rootScope.$root.name = 'anonymous'; 
}

function MyCtrl2($scope) {
    var name = $rootScope.$root.name;
}
```

Comment: $rootScope is undefined when you use it this way.