# AngularJs Moving data to redirected page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I am trying to use data in a redirected page which is redirected in angular.
How can I move data in this case. I tried using in rootscope but is this preferable? is ther any way where I can use the data from first page and use it in the page after redirection?

```
var app = angular.module('urlApp', []);
app.controller('urlCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $window) {
    $scope.ClickMeToRedirect = function () {
    $scope.myData = datafrommyDb;//This is what I am planning to use in redirected page
        var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/Account/Login";
        $log.log(url);
        $window.location.href = url;
    };
});
```

Comment: you can use with `param` attribute of `.state` method

Comment: Is datafrommyDb contains complex object or simple datatype like string,int,..?

Comment: you can send complete object. I have added answer with dummy object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use data across different controllers, you can use angular service. Since service are singleton object, the same object is getting injected to different controllers. $rootScope is not preferred because it is common to all the controllers and we might not be using the data in all the controllers. 
check this links

[$rootScope vs. service - Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331102/rootscope-vs-service-angular-js)

[Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular-ui-router  than you can follow below approach

add `params` attribute in `.state`

```
.state("nextPage", {
        url: '/nextpage',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/next.html',
        controller: 'NextController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        params: {
            alpha: null,
            beta: null
        },
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Next Page'
        }
    });
```

now on current page

```
 var params = { alpha :'alpha', beta:  'beta'}
 $state.go('nextPage', params);
```

on the nextpage

```
 angular
     .module('app')
     .controller('NextController', function($log, $state) {
         var vm = this;

         $log.log(' $state.params', $state.params);

         if ($state.params.alpha !== null && $state.params.beta !== null) {
             vm.whatevervariable = $state.params.alpha;
             vm.anothervariable = $state.params.beta;
         }
});
```