# How can I run function in two separated controllers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-events

I have two separate angularjs controllers
that are named `HomeController` and `SearchController`.

I have a function that named `Search()` in `HomeController`.

How can I run search function from `searchController`?

Answer (score 1):

define the 'search' function in a factory, inject that factory into both controllers then you can access 'search' function from both controllers.

sample:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function(searchFactory){
   //calling factory function
   //searchFactory.search();

});

app.controller('searchController ', function(searchFactory){

   //calling factory function
   //searchFactory.search();

});

app.factory('searchFacotry', function(){
  return{
    search: function(arg){
      alert('hello world');
    };
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made this  [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LKaaKQqiZ75oMzllLJNe?p=preview) which does the above. The app.js file looks like this. It uses a factory declaration. Alternatively if you just want this function to store and return some data then you can use $rootScope service of angular, it is accessible globally. Services are prefered when they are performing some operation. Take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331102/rootscope-vs-service-angular-js) which have answers explaining the use of services vs rootScope.

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, searchService) {
$scope.ctrl1Fun= function() {
    searchService.search();
}
});

app.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, searchService) {
      $scope.ctrl2Fun= function() {
       searchService.search();
      }
})

app.factory('searchService', function(){
  function search(){
    alert('hello World')
  }
  var service = {search : search}
  return service
});
```

Comment: I Want run function that is  in HomeController

Comment: If you need to reuse a function written inside a controller, you should take that function out and make it available through a service or share it through shared scope or rootscope. That's the standard practice, it makes your code reusable and less redundant.