# $rootScope vs top most ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering this:

Should we assign the commonly* used variables inside `$rootScope` or should we declare them in a top-most parent `ng-controller`?

- Commonly as in "used by many controllers"

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question very similar to the [Global variables in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11938380/1418796)

Generally speaking you should try to avoid putting things on a `$rootScope` as it is AngularJS equivalent of a global `window` scope. Since the `$rootScope` can be injected everywhere (services, directives etc.) variables declared on the root scope a truly global.

If you've got a top-most, app-level controller and sticking variables in there does the trick for you I would favor this over polluting the `$rootScope`. As a general rule of thumb we should be using the most restrictive / lower-level scope.

Don't forget that a service might be an answer here.