# Is there a place where I can define a global $scope.data variable in my AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs

I use `$scope.data.xxxx` etc in many places in my AngularJS application. Right now I am declaring $scope.data in each controller like this:

```
$scope.data = {}
```

Is there a better place for me to do this. For example could I better do this when setting up my app.js file in the .config or .run ?

Comment: is `$scope.data` the same values in every case?  is it config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numerous places you can put it

```
var app= angular.module('myApp',[])
```

As service

```
app.factory('myData',function(){
  return { foo:'bar'}

});
```

As Value

```
app.value( 'myData', { foo:'bar'});
```

As constant

```
app.constant( 'myData', { foo:'bar'});
```

In each case would inject `myData` in controller, directive, another service etc to access it

```
app.controller('SomeController',function($scope, myData){
   $scope.data=myData;
})
```

Comment: I assumed the global `myData` could be updated in a page and get persistent to other pages. But somehow it didn't work. Can you please show us in your example how an update is performed? Thanks.

Comment: @Blaise should be fairly easy by creating a getter and setter in a factory or service

Answer (score 3):

You can use at least 2 options:

- Use `$rootScope` as storage.
- Use `service`.  Services are singletons that you can inject to any controller and expose their values in a controller's scope.

I suggest you to use `service` (at least for me, its better way). from `$rootScope` **all** controllers can see your *globals*,

Good example how to use Service as storage you can see in <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/794/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Not really. if your application has a root controller that the others are nested inside you could set `$scope.data` there, but that probably doesn't do what you want - all of your controllers would use the same `data` object. If one controller changed it, it would change in every other controller as well.

Because (I presume) you want a separate `$scope.data` in each controller, you should continue to initialise each one separately.

Comment: Actually I don't need a separate $scope.data in each controller. How about in the .run or .config could I do it there ?

Comment: In that case there are three options - use a parent controller (attached to, say, body), use $rootScope or define a custom service. See this answer for more detail - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938380/global-variables-in-angularjs?rq=1