# Setting up global variable in SPA (Hot Towel)

Tags: global-variables, viewmodel, hottowel, single-page-application

I want to have a global variable that is accessible to modify in any view in my application. I am wondering what this the best way to do so when using hot towel. Currently, I am declareing this variable in my shell.js and referencing this in subsequent views.
My shell.js returns the global variable. My other views have the shell defined at the top like `define(['viewmodels/shell'], function(shell){}` and I access the shell variable like `shell.variablename`. I am wondering if this is the best way of handling variables that need to be accessed by more than one view.

Comment: Using $rootScope is generally considered good practice. [Here is link to similar question with answer][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938380/global-variables-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in many ways , either u create a config.js or any file or u can include the following code inside 'vm' object.

// config.js

```
define(function () {

    var variableName= 'BlahBlah';

    return {
        debugEnabled: ko.observable(true),
        variableName :variableName 
    };
});
```

// include this config.js in any javascript file

```
define(['folderName/config'],
    function (config) {
                  var x=  config.variableName;
                      }
```

This will work