# Changing $scope variable value in controller not changing value on view

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope, ng-view

I am working on Cordova tool and angularjs for my application.

```
cordovaApp.controller("VacationCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.tempdate = "2222";
        $scope.ruleDetails = function () {
        $scope.tempdate = "3333";
    }
});
```

view 1

```
<div ng-controller="VacationCtrl">
    <a ng-repeat="data in rules" ng-click="ruleDetails()" class="summaryListBorder" href="#detailVacationRule">
    </a>
</div>
```

view 2

```
<div ng-controller="VacationCtrl">
    {{tempdate}}
</div>
```

In above given code, I sat value of `$scope.tempdate` to "2222". When I am click on link, it calls `ruleDetails()` and set `$scope.tempdata = "3333".` But when the new page is open with `ng-view`, it shows only old value, i.e. "2222". I want to change it with "3333". I have tried with `$scope.$apply()` too.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have two views with the same name "VacationCtrl"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `ng-controller` attribute creates a new instance of the controller, which won't share the same scope as other instances. You want to wrap both `div`s in a single controller instance, like:

```
<div ng-controller="VacationCtrl">
    <div>
        <a ng-click="ruleDetails()" href="#detailVacationRule">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div>
        {{ tempdate }}
    </div>
</div>
```

If you need separate controllers, then you want to move common functions/fields into a service, which operates as a singleton so you can use it to share information between controllers. Or you could contain the separate controller instances in a parent controller, which will hold common fields and can be accessed through each controller's scope.

Comment: I can't do this. I have two different views for same controller.
If I create {{template}} on the same view, then all the things will be shown up at a time.

Comment: You should do this, otherwise your tempdate value won't change. your href will always default to $scope.tempdate being initialized to 2222.

Comment: Thanks for replying, But still I am not clear with this.
I want to open other view based on user clicks particular record. 
If you have any working example, then please suggest me.

Comment: With angular there are many ways to skin a cat, so it's hard to give you a solution without knowing your exact problem. Have a look at this other SO answer though and let me know if you're still unsure:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11938785/4044584

Comment: Thank you, for now I have created different controller for different functionality. and it is working... thx