# Using CDN with <img> tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cdn, content-delivery-network

I have just added a CDN service to make my website load faster.
I have a question regarding photos that are fetched using a `<img>` tag.

I have many cases like this:

```
// userProfile.thumbnailPhotoSrc = some/relative/path.png    
ng-src="{{userProfile.thumbnailPhotoSrc}}"
```

(I use AngularJS).

On startup, I have a script that saves the CDN endpoint to `window.cdn` variable. **In case the script decides there's no endpoint available:**

```
window.cdn = '';
```

So I want to be able to do something like:

```
ng-src="window.cdn + {{userProfile.thumbnailPhotoSrc}"
```

But this is impossible, as `window.cdn` is not evaluated. But neither this is working:

```
ng-src="{{window.cdn + userProfile.thumbnailPhotoSrc}"
```

Because I can only access `$scope` properties under `{{}}`.
I can't save the CDN endpoint to `$scope`, because there exists a `$scope` for every controller (I have many, this is not maintainable).

The last thing I thought of, hoping `ng-src` allows that - is adding a transformation function that is run on any `ng-src` attribute, but I could not find how to do that.

What do you suggest I do? keep in mind that I would like the website fetch the photo from the CDN and fallback to the origin server (fetch the relative path) in case of CDN malfunction. How can I obtain that behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Hi johni, how are you getting images from a CDN? Do you ultimately want to hit an endpoint of an API to retrieve image data?  Also, just a small tip - you don't need the "{{}}" inside the quotes. Sometimes this messes things up.

Comment: I use the same relative path that this `userProfile.thumbnailPhotoSrc` holds just with a different domain. For example: `'https://blabla.cdn.com/' + {{userProfile.thumbnailPhotoSrc}}` - would be evaluated to the right address of the CDN.

Comment: I think this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938380/global-variables-in-angularjs

Comment: In your example code you write `window.CDN` and `window.cdn`. Is this by accident or could this be related to your problem?

Comment: By mistake :), edited.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) in Angular

You would then have then in your templates:

```
ng-src="{{userProfile.thumbnailPhotoSrc | cdn}"
```

You could add the `$window` service as a dependency to the filter service so you don't have to pull it from the global object and you can test the filter as well.

Comment: This is nice, I wasn't aware of this but what if I have 1000 <img> tags? I need to go over all of these. I'm looking for a way to avoid that.

Comment: @johni — Surely the same way that you would deal with 1000 img tags if you didn't want to push them through the filter?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update all the `<img>` tag's src. You can create a directive:

```
angular.module('imageCdnSrc', [])
.directive('img',['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var ngSrc = attrs.ngSrc;
      delete attrs.ngSrc; // prevent ngSrc directive to trigger

      return function($scope,element,attrs) {
        var ngSrcVal = $interpolate(ngSrc)($scope); //returns the string value of ngSrc

        /* Add Logic Below to decide what to do */
        if(window.cdn && ngSrcVal && ngSrcVal.length>0){
          attrs.ngSrc = window.cdn + ngSrcVal;
          /* if image fails to load with cdn, load the default */
          element.one('error', function() {
            angular.element(this).attr("src", ngSrcVal);
          });
        }
        else{
          attrs.ngSrc = ngSrcVal;
        }
      };      
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: What makes this execute before the `$observe`'s callback of the ngSrc directive?

Comment: @johni Ok I updated so before it compiles it will append window.cdn to th ngSrc

Comment: In cases where `ng-src="{{userProfile.thumbnailPhotoSrc}}"` the directive's compile function is being called before the `{{}}` is evaluated.

Comment: @johni yes, that's how it works. The img 'src' won't render until after both. Here's an example of it working on plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/PGNWoF1w1OdmEFUSglKw?p=info

Comment: @johni I just updated the code to demonstrate before it gets evaluated and after.