# Change of value isn´t persistent between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m trying to store some kind of global variable in my application. I read that it´s best practice to use a value instead of a service or a rootscope.
So I created this code snippet to test the behavior of the value. It seems that the value changes indside of the controller but if I use the value in another controller, the change seems to be lost.
Is there a way to change the value during runtime and why is the change not persistant ?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6444/) is my code on jsfiddle

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.value("basePath", "");

myApp.controller('TestController', function($scope, basePath) {

    $scope.preEdit = basePath;

  basePath = window.location.href;
  $scope.postEdit = basePath;

});

myApp.controller('SampleController', function($scope, basePath) {
    $scope.transferedValue = basePath;
})
```

---

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
 Before Editing: {{preEdit}}<br>
 After Editing: {{postEdit}}<br>
</div>

<div ng-controller="SampleController">
  In another Controller: {{transferedValue}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find an answer in this entry: [Global variables in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938380/global-variables-in-angularjs)

Define the value as an Object

```
myApp.value("basePath", {value: ""});
```

After that you can change `basePath.value` in your controllers.

```
myApp.controller('TestController', function($scope, basePath) {

    $scope.preEdit = basePath.value;

  basePath.value = window.location.href;
  $scope.postEdit = basePath.value;

});
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use this value in a service instead of a controller?

Comment: Yes, you can use and change the value also in services.

Answer (score 1):

use a constant,

```
myApp.constant( 'basePath', '' );
```

this will allow you to inject the value into modules.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.postEdit = window.location.href;
});

app.controller('SampleController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.transferedValue = $rootScope.postEdit;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="TestController" ng-bind="postEdit"></div>
  <div ng-controller="SampleController" ng-bind="transferedValue"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

hai JohnDizzle ,

```
   You Can Pass the Data from One Controller to Anthor Controller Using BroadCast . And You can Store The LocalStorage And Retrive In Anthor Controll ALSO .. If Have Any Doughts Ask me.
```

Comment: It should be a comment, since you have no enough reputation to comment, you should post a real answer.