# Global variable in AngularJS (good practice)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm looking for a pattern in order to have globals constant in my application. But not with a controller or a factory. (so not with app.constant() too)

I just want to set a variable but I didn't find something good.

I wanted to set this var in my rootScoop but without success.
with something like

```
myApp.run(function($rootScoop){
$rootScoop.global = {};
});
```

When I use that code, an arror occurs for nothing (transtateFilterProvider). When I delete this code, the translateService works,

I MUST have access in all html view, I don't want to always use a controller (useless in this case), I just want to set a global variable in rootScoop.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a factory/service? That seems like the angular way of doing it. If you really don't want to use that, you could try writing you variables on the global object (`window`) using pure JS (no angular):
`window.constants = {}`

Comment: I want to access in HTML view, is that possible with windows.constants ?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. Try it out either using `window.constants` or `window["constants"]`. If that doesn't work you could expose that on the template's controller (scope).

Comment: actually I can inject my var in rootScope but when I do it, my injector throw an exception for nothing ... 
If I delete first line, it's works fine.
`var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.constants =  {
      "client": {
        'name' : 'client'
      }
    };
    console.log($rootScope);
});
`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to say. ;) In your controller you could do following to expose the global constants object to the "angular world": `$scope.constants = window.constants` - but be aware that you would need to do this in all controllers where you want to access your constants.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variables in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938380/global-variables-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because it is :

```
$rootScope
```

And not

```
$rootScoop
```

Anyway, correct way to do this is to add a constant module to your app like :

```
angular.module('yourapp', []).constant('Constants', {
    foo: 'bar'
});
```

But you'll have to call Constants in controllers.

If you use $rootScope, remember you will need to call $root.global in templates.