# Global Variables in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular 2 based app. I want to have a global variable that can be accessed and also modified by all components. 
All current answers I am able to find are for constants. Can anyone suggest how I can do so ? 
Thanks!

Comment: I believe a shared service would be the way to go: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938380/global-variables-in-angularjs) answer your question?

Comment: To start with, are you sure it is a good idea to have global variables at all?

Comment: I have a http request that is fired off every 5 minutes. I need a global variable to turn it off if the user clicks on the unsubscribe button

Comment: if the flag value can be changed across many components, than yeah, a singletone service approach would be the best

Comment: You still can put it in `environment.ts`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo the value doesnt stay changed across multiple components

Comment: doesnt stay changed? what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

When I have to deal with global variable I usually do it via shared services. I declare a variable in root component's service, which is usually `app.service.ts` and make it available to other components via setter and getter functions.

To demonstrate, I used a heroes tutorial plunker that has three components. In the `app.service.ts` I declared a variable `myGlobalVar`.

I added buttons in all other components to change the value of `myGlobalVar` and lookup it's value at anytime.

You can find interaction details from this [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/juF6ICGAqPbXkEHkBuFW?p=preview)

app.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
    myGlobalVar;

    constructor(){
      this.myGlobalVar = true;
      console.log("My global variable value: " + this.myGlobalVar);
      alert("My intial global variable value is: " + this.myGlobalVar);
    }

    setMyGV(val: boolean){
      console.log("Setting FV to: " + val);
      this.myGlobalVar = val;
    }

    getMyGV(val: boolean){
      return this.myGlobalVar;
    }
}
```

Accessing and modifying the variable from a component:

```
export class exampleComponent{
  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}

  changeGV(val){
      this.appService.setMyGV(val);
    }

    showGV(){
      alert("GV: " + this.appService.getMyGV());
    }
}
```