# Initialize Constant Using ng-init Variables in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with `AngularJs` and I am initializing a variable in the `ng-init` of that model.

```
<body ng-init="allowedState=2" ng-controller="amCtrl">
</body>
```

Now what I want is to declare a `constant` using this variable which will then be shared within the app.

```
angular.module('amModule').constant('temp', ?)
```

I am trying to figure this out and I am now wondering if it's even possible?

Comment: you can add those values to `$rootScope` to access anywhere in the app. Although it is not a good practice. But for simple scenarios, you can add variables in  `$rootScope`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the above way

```
angular.module('amModule').constant('allowedState',2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-init;

```
ng-init="loader(); firstName = 'John'"
```

It's better not to use the ng-init instead use below methods;

You can constants or values for initializing variables;
[Official angular doc link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide)

Example:
With Constant:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.constant('appName', 'Application Name');

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['appName', function TestCtrl(appName) {
    console.log(appName);
}]);
```

With Values:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.value('usersOnline', 0);
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['usersOnline', function TestCtrl(usersOnline) {
    console.log(usersOnline);
    usersOnline = 15;
    console.log(usersOnline);
}]);
```

Also, using service is good solution;
[Using rootScope and service method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938380/global-variables-in-angularjs)

Thanks,